# Fastest way to solve Gram Schmidt orthogonalization in quantum computer

Tags: quantum-algorithms, unitarity

Suppose we have $n$ (large) dimensional vector space and I want to orthogonalize $n$ linearly independent vectors using the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process. Is there some time-bound on how quickly a quantum computer can complete this process? Or is there any best known quantum algorithm for this?

Comment: It is pretty efficient classically. (This also gives a bound.)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you think quantum computers could be faster than classical ones?

Comment: Seeing Norbert's answer, I looked up its classical complexity. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986225/computational-complexity-of-gram-schmidt-orthogonalization-algorithm/27986858

Comment: @fqq I was thinking $n$ to be around $2^50$ or something, I don't have any knowledge on how fast classical computers can do this, but this is a pretty big dimension. So I thought maybe quantum computer can manage such large dimensions.

Comment: The issue is that if you want exactly the Gram-Schmidt output, the output vectors are necessarily defined in a very linear way, one after the other. So it feels very unlikely that you could find something faster (obviously this is not a rigorous statement).