# An algorithm to perform Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization of linearly independent state vectors

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms, circuit-construction, unitarity

In the first paragraph of the 2nd section of this [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.2583), it is stated that given a set of linearly independent $n$-qubit state vectors, Alice can perform the Gram-Schmidt procedure to obtain orthogonal quantum states.

But I know the Gram-Shmidt process is not a unitary operation, so is it possible to come up with an algorithm, using ancillary qubits or something?
I.e., if we have $M$ arbitrary, linearly independent $n$-qubit state vectors $\{ |x_1\rangle, |x_2\rangle, |x_3\rangle, \cdots , |x_M\rangle \}$ do we have an algorithm to perform Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization on this set to obtain a set of mutually orthogonal state vectors and can we construct the corresponding circuit?

Comment: You shouldn't link to libgen as it is blocked in many countries. There appears to be an arxiv version of the paper anyway.

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/17955/55 and https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/18037/55. Are you asking about a classical or a quantum algorithm here? Could you spell out the difference between this question and https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/17955/55?

Comment: @glS Both questions are related but in that, I was interested in the maximum number of steps required only. But here I actually want to understand the mentioned article and interested in an actual quantum circuit to perform such an operation.